# Use of UTP patch cables on a STP cabled network

Tags: utp

In the walls of the building there are Cat6a FTP cables.

Can we use Cat6 UTP patch cables to our switches, 
and maintain 1Gbs speed?

Or do we need to use FTP cables all the way from switch to end point?

Answer (score 0):

You can, it will probably work, but your FTP cables will be totally useless...

If 99% of the cable path is FTP, but not connected to ground (ideally at each side), there is no protections against EMI.

So use FTP cables, you will never ask yourself if the problem you are working on is due to this 2 meter UTP patch panel.